# How to "glue" a rigged model to an animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, .fbx

In Blender (2.90.1): What steps need to be done to combine a rigged character model (from a .blend file) with an animation from a .fbx file?
What I've tried so far is this:

1. Open the model from the .blend file.
2. Import the animation from the .fbx file.

The result can be seen at this screenshot:
[image]
The (thin black) stick figure represents the animation from the .fbx file. Pushing play at the timeline plays its animation.

Now the question is, what needs to be done to transfer the animation from the stick figure to the cowboy model? I.e. How can you make the cowboy walk?

You help is very much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pose mode, there's an option to add `Bone Constraints` (Below the Bone Context).
[image]

Select `Add Bone Constraint` - `Copy Rotation`, and select the corresponding bone in the other rig as `Target`.

"Corresponding" is a bit arbitrary, since for example, the cowboy rig doesn't have hip bones. So you will need to play around a bit with the options available, like `Invert`.